# Getting Error while running RED5 server - class path resource [red5.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: linux, red5

HI ,

I have installed java version "1.6.0_14" and Ant version 1.8.2 for red5 Server. when i am trying to run red5 server i am getting the following error please help

Root: /usr/local/red5 Deploy type: bootstrap Logback selector: org.red5.logging.LoggingContextSelector Setting default logging context: default 11:27:39.838 [main] INFO org.red5.server.Launcher - Red5 Server 1.0.0 RC1 $Rev: 4171 $ (http://code.google.com/p/red5/) Red5 Server 1.0.0 RC1 $Rev: 4171 $ (http://code.google.com/p/red5/) SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/red5/red5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/red5/lib/logback-classic-0.9.26.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation. 11:27:39.994 [main] INFO o.s.c.s.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@39d85f79: startup date [Mon Dec 21 11:27:39 EST 2009]; root of context hierarchy 11:27:40.149 [main] INFO o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [red5.xml] Exception org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [red5.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [red5.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist Bootstrap complete

Answer (score 1):

ok. so the instructions at the website sent you and me on a bit of a wrong turn.

What you need to do is build red5 dist using

```
ant clean dist
```

as shown here

http://trac.red5.org/wiki/Install

then cd into the dist directory

```
cd <checkout-path>/dist
```

then do

```
export RED5_HOME=`pwd`
```

then run ./red5.sh

basically the red5.sh script using RED5_HOME to workout where the conf/red.xml file is.. if you dont set it, or as the instructions say, set it in the root directory of the checkout then it cant find conf/red5.xml and all the other ones.

hope this helps someone in the future.

Cheers

Mark

Answer (score 1):

That means you don't have conf file in the `red5` directory.

```
cd /usr/local/red5
cp -r dist/conf .
./red5.sh &
```